# How can I use json values as columns in a query SQL?

Tags: json, sql-server

I just want to receive a json data and use it's fields as a table column for another queries.

I'm trying to make the value in the key "nameProperty" into a column in a table, and the value of the keys "newValue"fill the rows of that column.

For example:

i get a json file like this

```
{ 
   "operation":{ 
      "ID":"ABC",
      "KinshipDescription":"--"
   },
   "fields":[ 
      { 
         "property":{ 
            "nameProperty":"ID",
            "oldValue":"",
            "newValue":"123456",
            "confirmed":"false",
            "labelProperty":"ID",
            "oldValueDescription":"",
            "newValueDescription":"123456"
         }
      },
      { 
         "property":{ 
            "nameProperty":"Name",
            "oldValue":"",
            "newValue":"John",
            "confirmed":"false",
            "labelProperty":"Name",
            "oldValueDescription":"",
            "newValueDescription":"John"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to extract the objects on the list "fields", but i only can make them an row for key, and another row for values like the script below makes.

```sql
DECLARE @jsonObj NVARCHAR(MAX)
--Set a result in 
SET @jsonObj = (select JSON_Query(data, '$.fields') from table where id = 'ABC')

select * from openjson(@jsonObj) 
with (Property nvarchar(255) '$.property.nameProperty',
 newValue nvarchar(50) '$.property.newValue')
```

and I have no idea how I can do this

the results of this script is something like this

```
ID  123456
Name    John
```

and the results that i want to see is

```
ID      Name --column name, not a row
123456  John
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest (thought-wise, not necessarily performance) way I can come up with on this is using dynamic SQL. In fact, I'm pretty certain you'll have to use it.

Here's an example that can get you moving. You can run this in SSMS.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) =
'{ 
   "operation":{ 
      "ID":"ABC",
      "KinshipDescription":"--"
   },
   "fields":[ 
      { 
         "property":{ 
            "nameProperty":"ID",
            "oldValue":"",
            "newValue":"123456",
            "confirmed":"false",
            "labelProperty":"ID",
            "oldValueDescription":"",
            "newValueDescription":"123456"
         }
      },
      { 
         "property":{ 
            "nameProperty":"Name",
            "oldValue":"",
            "newValue":"John",
            "confirmed":"false",
            "labelProperty":"Name",
            "oldValueDescription":"",
            "newValueDescription":"John"
         }
      }
   ]
}';

-- Variable to hold the column/values.
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

-- Generate the column/value pairs.
SELECT 
    @cols = @cols
        + CASE WHEN ( LEN( @cols ) > 0 ) THEN ', ' ELSE '' END -- add comma if needed.
        + '''' + Properties.newValue + ''' AS [' + Properties.nameProperty + '] '
FROM OPENJSON( @json, '$.fields' ) WITH (
    property NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.property' AS JSON
)
CROSS APPLY (

    SELECT * FROM OPENJSON( property ) WITH (
        nameProperty VARCHAR(50) '$.nameProperty',
        oldValue     VARCHAR(50) '$.oldValue',
        newValue     VARCHAR(50) '$.newValue',
        confirmed    VARCHAR(50) '$.confirmed',
        labelProperty VARCHAR(50) '$.labelProperty',
        oldValueDescription VARCHAR(50) '$.oldValueDescription',
        newValueDescription VARCHAR(50) '$.newValueDescription'
    )

) AS Properties;

-- Execute column/value pairs as dynamic SQL.
EXEC ( 'SELECT ' + @cols );
```

Which returns:

```
+--------+------+
|   ID   | Name |
+--------+------+
| 123456 | John |
+--------+------+
```

If you were to PRINT @cols you would see

```
'123456' AS [ID] , 'John' AS [Name]
```

**A few quick notes:**

- Performance may vary.
- Values are quoted but can be **CAST** if needed.
- Included all 'property' fields in **CROSS APPLY** for example. Only specify what is needed.
- Note the use of **NVARCHAR** when using `AS JSON`
- May want to consider **OUTER APPLY** if there's potential for no 'property' present.

Comment: Thank you very much! I could not think of anything like this. Helped me a lot!